# foreach control c# skipping controls

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, controls, enumeration

I have the following loop to remove the buttons in my C# Windows Forms application. The only problem is that it skips every other button. How do I go about removing all the button controls from my form?

```
foreach (Control cntrl in Controls)
{
    if(cntrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        Controls.Remove(cntrl);
        cntrl.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't check, but I would expect this code to produce an exception, because you can't modify a collection (`Controls`) while looping through it.

Comment: I don't get any error in either the execution or in the error list. What do you suggest?

Comment: this code will throw Invalid Operation exception may be you would have wrapped this code with try and catch in any of parent methods

Comment: I am so glad I was able to track down this question. I had the exact same problem and was trying to search for a solution and it took a while to get the correct search terms. It does not, in fact, give an error, even without a try and catch, which I agree is strange.

Comment: I found the issue raised by @defaultlocale and other commenters has already been asked about in [Why does ControlCollection NOT throw InvalidOperationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35084463/150605).  I have deleted my comments here and reposted them as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617330/150605) on that question.  I linked to this question in that answer, so that question will at least always appear in the Linked section on the right for this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this way is a bit more readable:

```
var controlsToRemove = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();
foreach (var control in controlsToRemove)
{
    Controls.Remove(control);
    cntrl.Dispose();
}
```

Calling `ToArray()` makes a new concrete collection, so that you can enumerate over one and modify the other.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised that's not erroring on you, since you're modifying the collection as you're iterating over it.  Use a `for` loop and start at the end:

```
for (int ii = Controls.Count - 1; ii >= 0; ii--)
{
    Control cntrl = Controls[ii];
    Controls.remove(cntrl);
    cntrl.Dispose();
}
```

(Starting at the end because otherwise you'd be changing the indexes of each control as you iterated.)

Comment: Hmm, so you can't remove a ladder while you stand on it? Thanks for explaining the mistake. When trying your method I got an error that there was no definition for Length. I probably tried it wrong.

Comment: It's probably `.Count` instead of `.Length` - I didn't verify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Youre iterating over the same collection from whitch youre removing. Use this code:

```
    List<Control> cleanControls = new List<Control>();
    foreach(Control ctr in Controls)
    {
       if(cntrl.GetType() != typeof(Button))
       {
          cleanControls.Add(ctr);
       }
       else
       {
         ctr.Dispose();
       }
    } 
    Controls = cleanControls;
```

That's It!
Hope I helped!