# Why does this delete every other checkbox?

Tags: c#, checkbox, panel

Rank noob again learning C# with Winforms. I was practicing adding checkboxes to a panel, and then removing them. The "start_button" button adds checkboxes. This works. The "remove_button" button is supposed to delete all of them. But it doesn't. By playing around with the # of checkboxes, I figured out that it removes every other checkbox. Another click and it removes every other of the remaining ones, and so on until they are all gone.

Why?

Thanks,
Aram

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace playingWithPanels
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CheckBox chkBox;
    TextBox txtBox;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void start_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.BringToFront();
        txtBox.Text = "Textbox";
        txtBox.Location = new Point(30, 10);
        panel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
        for (int i =0;i<20;i++)
        {
        chkBox = new CheckBox();
        chkBox.BringToFront();
        chkBox.Text = "Checkbox_" + i.ToString();
        chkBox.Name = "Checkbox_" + i.ToString();
            chkBox.AutoSize = true;
        chkBox.Location = new Point(30, 40 + 25 * i);
        panel1.Controls.Add(chkBox);
        }
    }

    private void remove_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            panel1.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count()` at the **start** of the `remove_button_Click` code? At the end?

Comment: It's generally bad to modify a collection as you are iterating over it (especially with `foreach`).  See the remarks section of [`IEnumerable.GetEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator#remarks) where it states "If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the behavior of the enumerator is undefined."  I cannot explain the specific behavior you're seeing, but I'd say it qualifies as "undefined".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [foreach control c# skipping controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627038/foreach-control-c-sharp-skipping-controls)

Answer (score 4):

Because you use iterator and modify collection during that. Use the following approach:

```
    var controls = panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray();
    foreach (var ctrl in controls)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
    }
```